DataBricks API not working for Create or Update
I have this problem
{
    "error_code": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "Remote repo not found. Please ensure that:\n1. Your remote Git repo URL is valid.\n2. Your personal access token or app password has the correct repo access."
}

Context: I want to update a repo using Azure DevOps but following the documentation from Databricks API is not working
    - bash: |

   URL="$(DATABRICKS-HOST)/api/2.0/repos/{REPO_ID}"

   JSON_PAYLOAD='{
     "branch": "{BRANCH}",
     "sparse_checkout": {
       "patterns": [
         "parent-folder/child-folder"
       ]
     }
   }'

   curl -v --location --request PATCH "$URL" \
     --header "Authorization: Bearer $DATABRICKS_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --header "X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token: $ENTRAID_TOKEN" \
     --header "X-Databricks-Org-Id: {ORG_ID}" \
     --header "X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id: /subscriptions/{SUBID}/resourceGroups/{RG}/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/{DATABRICKS-NAME}" \
     --data "$JSON_PAYLOAD"

I can do GETS to permissions, and for the repos.
My App registration has permission over the databricks (Admin group, Manager and User inside of databricks) also has permission over Azure DevOps. I don't think it is a permission problem.

Have you verified all variables in the URL and headers have been set correctly? I often find undefined or invalid parameters being the cause.

how are you generating bearer token from app registration,add those details

also what you are giving in {REPO_ID}


{
"error_code": "BAD_REQUEST",
"message": "Remote repo not found. Please ensure that:\n1. Your remote Git repo URL is valid.\n2. Your personal access token or app password has the correct repo access."
}

Error that says "Remote repo not found".
The error message says that the remote Git repo URL is not valid or the personal access token or app password does not have the correct repo access.

Make sure that the remote Git repository URL linked to the
REPO_ID in Databricks is accurate and accessible.
You can test Git Connection manually clone the repository using the
service principal's credentials to validate that access is working
correctly.

Thank you @AlexOtt for the documentation about how to Use Repos to work on your own copy of notebooks, test them by committing changes to the "staging" environment, and promote them to "production" after successfully testing the releases branch.
Below are the steps you can follow:
Setup on Databricks Side
Configure Azure DevOps Pipelines:
Create a variable group to store common configurations.
Set up a build pipeline.
Set up a release pipeline.
Reference: SO link
